How can I sync replicas with each other?
I have two replicas for my main cassandra server. Both the replicas are not in sync with the main server. This happened because the replica servers were running into errors cause by commit logs for 3 days in a row. So the replica servers don't have data for these three dates in almost every table. So, how can I bring these replica servers in sync with the main cassandra server which has complete data !
If we can do this at the server level then how can we perform it ?
The cassandra version - 3.11.1
I haven't tried anything yet since this is a production level cluster.
I expect to bring all the replica servers in sync with the main cassandra server. I want the entire data present on the main server to be readily available on the replica servers.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

You need to manually run repairs to synchronise the replicas.
In Cassandra, the repair operation (1) compares data between replicas to determine if they are inconsistent, and (2) "repairs" them by sending the latest copy/version from another replica.
The most efficient way to run a repair is to with the partitioner range option (-pr). You need to run the following command one node at a time, on all nodes in all DCs:
$ nodetool repair -pr

Note that if you have incremental repair enabled on your cluster, run the repair command on its own (without the -pr flag) so that the SSTables which are already repaired don't have to be processed again.
If you're new to Cassandra, watch the short video on Repair (DS210.18) on the Apache Cassandra Operations playlist on YouTube so you can get the basics.
You might also be interested in the following resources:

Blog - Repairs in Cassandra by Jeremiah Jordan
Hands-on course - (free) Cassandra Fundamentals at DataStax.com/dev

